# What are the performance/memory differences between passing Javascript objects of different sizes?

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, memory, ecmascript-6

In Javascript, say I had two objects x and y. y is a subset of x through destructuring. If I were to pass one of these objects to another function many times, what would be the performance/memory implications? Originally I'd think y since it contains less data but in Javascript, objects are pass by reference - So am I right in assuming that either object will affect the memory of the function I'm calling equally?

Comment: JavaScript is call-by-value, better described as call-by-object-sharing. The values happen to be “references” (an implementation detail) for non-primitive types. As a result, *all objects take the same amount of (inconsequential) time to pass* as an argument; there is no “copy” or additional space required.

Comment: @user2864740 so is the purpose of destructuring arrays and objects just ensuring clean code and separating responsibilities (ie. not using functions/variables it doesn't require)?

Comment: That’s definitely a use, yes. Also, since restructuring (?) (to a new object) creates a new object, such may also be useful in cases to control side-effects. This can also be done without the newer/terse destructuring syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are passed to functions as pointers in Javascript.  So, it costs no more to pass a pointer to a large object than passing a pointer to a small object and there are no copies of the object made when it is passed as a function argument.   In either case (large object or small object), it's just passing a pointer to the object, not actually passing the object.  And, the memory usage of the function that is being called won't change whether the object passed to it is large or small.

Now if the function makes an explicit copy of the object it is passed (like with `Object.assign()` or with destructuring), then the memory use of the function will be affected by how big the object is that it's making a copy of, which I presume is entirely logical.